# ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder): no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to use code first migration approach(genrate database from code). but facing error. here is my code

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace IMChatApp.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase = false;
        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<JustDoIt.Models.user> users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you make the method public instead of protected?

Comment: for derived classes just type `override` > hit space > choose method from intellisense, leaves no room for such errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151754(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext%606.OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder)), the `OnModelCreating` method takes a `DbModelBuilder`, not a `ModelBuilder`.